# SQL Server C# Windows Service or SSIS (or DTS) for inserts/updates/deletes

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am in the process of making a decision for a future web application where users will have readonly access and they will only view data.
However the database is where all the heavy lifting will be done. What I am trying to determine is this..This application will be deployed on client servers..Now if I use SSIS or DTS packages am I not leaving the code and all the logic open for view and copy for the client?

Second if my above concern holds some water then I can write a windows Service and put all my rules/logic there, this way it will be a tad bit difficult to see my code and logic(some level of obfuscation)..But doing this way I am not sure how much of performance hit I will have to suffer?
This windows service will be updating/delete/inserts in SQL Server every minute or 2 24/7...The tables which are going to be impacted may have over or around 5 million+ records in them at the worst times.
I am inclined towards Windows Service, please suggest me make a better decision..as I mentioned..database inserts/updates/deletes are very going to be fairly active (every minute or 2, 24x7)..

Thanks

Comment: You're providing a product to clients and so your concern is that using a technology like SSIS or DTS would enable them to decipher your intellectual property and potentially provide a competing product/build their own?

Comment: What is the source of the data ? Flat files, non-SQL databases, web service calls ?

Comment: The plan is to allow multiple sources, such as a csv file, or a direct connection to another database for data to import from, apply business rules and then insert/update/delete into applications DB. It can not be direct connections between databases and I will have to have a middle staging application where data will be manipulated and then inserted.
And yes since plan is for the application to be installed on multiple client systems therefore I want some level of obfuscation ....some loss in speed may be tolerable

Comment: Well, you could do the initial import in SSIS to a SQL staging table, but then have the SSIS package call encrypted stored procs for the business logic you want obfuscated.